# Zend Studio Font-Color Scheme For Netbeans 7?

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio, netbeans-7, color-scheme

Can anyone provide me the font & color scheme which is similar to Zend Studio's default? (for Netbeans 7)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that theme. http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized